# Which one is preferable: Buffer.from() or TextEncoder.encode()?

Tags: javascript, node.js

From my understanding and API docs, in Node the following are equivalent and return an `Uint8Array`:

```
Buffer.from(someString, 'utf-8')
```

```
(new TextEncoder()).encode(someString)
```

Is either of those on the way of becoming deprecated? Does someone know of any considerations that make either  `Buffer` or `TextEncoder`/`TextDecoder` preferable over the other, if all that’s needed is converting UTF-8 strings to and from `Uint8Array`s?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my understanding, `Buffer` is Node’s original implementation of binary blobs before equivalent feature has made its way into browser JS runtime.

After browsers went with a different API, Node runtime incorporated that as well (which makes sense from code portability standpoint), and preserved the original buffer support.

As a result, in Node there are multiple ways of achieving roughly similar results when it comes to binary blobs, where some ways will also work in browser while others won’t. `Buffer.from()`/`TextEncoder.encode()` might be one of them.

I’m not sure if there’s any performance gain to be had by choosing “Node classic” `Buffer` API over browser-compatible `TextEncoder`.